# Golang: Is this an acceptable way to create a Slice from part of another Slice?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have searched around and have not found another example of this being done but I inadvertently discovered that I was able to create a slice from a fragment of another slice by simply passing that fragment to a function that accepts a slice and returning that slice.

Example:

```
   package main

import "fmt"

func makeSliceFrom(s []int) []int {
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    newS := makeSliceFrom(s[1:7])
    fmt.Println(newS)
}
```

I am not asking if this works, because I know it works and seems to work well, I am asking if this is supported or has some unforeseen cost that I am not aware of. It seems odd that I have not seen any examples of this being done.

Comment: That function doesn't do anything, it's effectively the same as direct assignment

Comment: Are you trying to create a new slice header that points to the same underlying array?  If so, as @JimB pointed out, just subslice directly (ex. `newS := s[1:7]`).  If you want it to _copy_ that subslice's data to a different underlying array (so changes to either one don't affect the other), use the built-in `copy()` function.

Comment: Ok I get it. I am new to go so I guess I misinterpreted what was happening there. That explains why I have not seen that technique before.

Comment: Read through the [go blog post on slices](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals), it's good to have a solid understanding of how slices and arrays relate to each other, otherwise you could have some surprises.

Answer (score -1):

A slice can be created with the built-in function called make, which has the signature,

```
func make([]T, len, cap) []T
```

Recommended Reading :

https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: not sure why this is getting downvoted. Its literally out of the docs